# REGEX C# (Matching beginning and ending word)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, match

I am using Regex to retrieve a paragraph.  My paragraph in my string variable contains the beginning letter, G. and it ends with a variable, @Variable.

What pattern would I use to use to grab that paragraph? I was using the code below but I think I am really off.

```
    Regex.Match(paragraph, @"\G. .*\@Variable$");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
string regex = @"G.+" + variable.ToString()
Regex.Match(paragraph, regex);
```

While you're at it grab a copy of [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) - makes tasks like this much easier.

Comment: Two things, first, why the `\G` there's no need to escape the G that I know of?  Second, I think you would want to do `.+` so that you get `one or more` rather than `zero or more`.

Comment: @CodingGorilla - Points taken - many thanks for pointing those out

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
Regex.Match(paragraph, string.Format(@"^G.*?{0}$", yourVariableHere));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want (if I'm understanding your requirements):

```
string regex = @"G.+" + variable;
Regex.Match(paragraph, regex);
```

A couple of things to note, you have to be careful what is in the `variable` if it contains things like `\` that is going to mess up your regex.  There are "reserved" characters in regex that you have to beware of so as not to cause problems.

Also, instead of `.*` I used `.+` which means "Between one and unlimited times" rather than "Between zero and unlimited times" so it requires that there is at least one other character in your "paragraph".  You may wish to add something like `.{10,}` which would establish a minimum of 10 characters, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  It worked but not as expected.  It seems that I have to choose another way of performing this task due to multiple cases of the letter G appearing.  So now, I am considering putting this particular paragraph in double brackets.  [[paragraph]], so when performing the regex I would be looking for everything in between the double brackets. Would the syntax now be:  string regex = @"[[.+" + "]]";

Comment: I decided to just go with substring for the double brackets. Thank you all again!